# differences between css({'font-size':'value'}) and css('font-sze') == value in jQuery css method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

What is difference between 
    `$('some element').css({'font-size':'15'})`
and
    `$('some element').css('font-size') == '15px'`
 Please look at this code:

```
 $('#wrapper').on('click', '#p6', function() {

     if ( $('a.sub').css({'font-size':'15'}) )  {
        $('a.sub').not('a.subEnroll').removeAttr('style').fadeOut(10);
     }
     else {
        $('a.sub').fadeOut(10); 
     }
  });
```

I wrote this IF clause and the condition, but it don't work.
What's wrong in this code?

Comment: where is your hover code.... also the html

Comment: `$('a.sub').css({'font-size':'15'})` returns true all the time.

Comment: Can you post your markup too? Also if possible create a fiddle?

Comment: sorry, I wrote click in on() method in the example, that's mouseenter in fact...
I'll creat a fiddle now...

Comment: http://mihanbit.com/download/524785650abc1/index1.css
http://mihanbit.com/download/524785609c7ec/submenus1.js

this is my css and jQuery files that you can Download it...

http://jsfiddle.net/CrND9/ this is HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Barmar; I get that 
for comparing current css value with the which one we want, we had to use
    `$('some element').css('some attr') == value` 
because the situation that I wrote in the question, is for set an attribute and alway will be true, so we can't use this in `if` clause as a condition...

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to test whether the font size is 15, it should be:

```
if ($('a.sub').css('font-size') == '15px') {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```